# Bubble sort and IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: .net, vb.net, bubble-sort, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to implement BubbleSort. However, I get an array out of bound error; this happens on the third line. Can someone explain to me what's going wrong?

```
For i As Integer = 0 To marks.Length Step 1
    For x As Integer = 0 To marks.Length - 1 Step 1
        If marks(x) > marks(x + 1) Then <<< "this where the problem is" 
            temp = marks(x + 1)
            marks(x + 1) = marks(x)
            marks(x) = temp
        End If
    Next x
Next i
For a As Integer = 0 To marks.Length
    MsgBox(marks(a))
Next
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have edited your question; I think it will be received better this way. If you disagree with the edit, you can roll it back. (Click on the "edited ... ago" text to get the rollback menu). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an off-by-one problem. x will go from 0 to `marks.Length-1`, but on the third line you try to get `marks(x + 1)`. However, as soon as x reaches it's maximum value of `marks.Length - 1`, this evaluates to `marks( x + 1 )` == `marks( (marks.Length - 1) + 1 )` == `marks( marks.Length )` - which is indeed out of bounds.

The `For` loop in the second line should use `marks.Length - 2`.
Disclaimer: do add a test to verify that your Bubble Sort still works correctly for edge cases if you make this change. You may have to tweak the algorithm a little further if it doesn't.